# Does the concept of the Master Bedroom exist in German Language/Culture?

Tags: translation, culture

In German Culture, does the concept of a Master Bedroom, exist? In America, most houses have a master bedroom that is constructed differently than the others, and is usually identified as such on the building plans.  It is usually the largest bedroom, and many times will have special construction considerations, such as it's own bathroom, bigger closets, restricted access, etc.

Comment: Mauser, welcome to the site! Your question *might* raise a few eyebrows as "lacking research" or "not about the language". As I think it's actually quite interesting, could you please add a bit of your own research (e.g. what does your dictionary say), please? You should take the [tour] and visit our [help] to get a better understanding how this site works and what makes a good question. Again, welcome!

Comment: Do you really mean the largest room in the house, or the largest _bedroom_ in the house? The former would be rather uncommon in Germany; normally the living room (possibly combined with the kitchen, in a more modern house) is largest.

Comment: I did a bit of research.  I have studied the language for more than 8 years.  I also have two brothers that each lived and worked in Germany, Austria, and Switzerland for 2 years, and can speak German quite fluently, but neither of them knew the answer. I also gained no traction searching the internet.  In my experience the best answers to cultural questions are to discuss with someone from that culture.

Comment: The expression master bedroom is not used  in German. If there is a second bedroom for guests it is the Gästezimmer.

Comment: The concept of a bedroom is different in US/Canada/UK from Germany.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes and no.

**No**, because we don't count bedrooms but "all-purpose-rooms" excluding kitchen and bathroom. You will find terms like

> Dreizimmerwohnung

meaning three rooms that could either be used as three separate bedrooms (like with college students sharing a flat), bedroom, guest room, office... whatever combination comes to mind or fits the life of the inhabitants.

**Yes**, because of course the main inhabitant(s) (or parents, for example) need their bedroom. But you wouldn't use a literal translation, instead it would be called

> - Elternschlafzimmer (in case of parents) or simply
> - Schlafzimmer (generic term).

*Non-Master bedrooms* on the other hand are typically specified in detail, either as

> - Kinderzimmer (yes, often even if said child is 25 years old),
> - Gästezimmer (for guests)
> - zweites (drittes / ...) Schlafzimmer (e.g. in case of a couple having separate bedrooms or a shared flat)
> - [Name of occupant]s Zimmer (if the child mentioned above rejects the term "Kinderzimmer")
> - ...

Comment: In my experience, the Kinderzimmer is often *larger* than the Elternschlafzimmer. After all, the Kinderzimmer is essentially the living space for the child, where the child spends much time also at daytime (and needs a lot of space for toys etc.), whereas bedrooms for adults are usually only used at night, for sleeping. Sure applied to my Kinderzimmer :)

Comment: How you use the rooms is up to the people who live there. In my childhood home, my parents originally did occupy the largest room beside the living room, but as soon as I got old enough to play unattended for a while, we did some in-house moving to swap bedrooms.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Yup. Because the alternative is LEGO all over the living room floor ^_^!

Comment: »Dreizimmerwohnung« or, regionally, »Dreiraumwohnung«

Comment: @ospalh - and of course there is also [Zweiraumwohnung](https://www.youtube.com/user/zweiraumwohnung)...

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it seems as if you all have experience with apartments.  Does anyone know if the same applies to houses?

Comment: @Mauser You are welcome. As far as the nomenclature of bedrooms goes, yes, it's the same.

Comment: Also, we usually don't have walk in closets in Germany. Instead we have a piece of furniture called Schrank where we put our clothes. (yes, Schrank is often translated with closet but in my experience Americans will assume walk-in-closet and Germans will assume piece-of-furniture-closet when you say closet).